# Mongoose multi query operators with expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, api-design

I'm trying to learn how to make an API. And I met a problem that transcends me. My problem is about to database queries. This is my endpoint;

```
/api/stats/:userId/:period/:type/:point?/
```

`:userId`is exacly user ID (and it's snowflake ID like twitter)

`:period` has always an timestamp. (and I will call it `start_date` later)

`:type` is user actions.

`:point?` is an optional argument and it's mean *spesific* user actions.

so, this is my mongoose schema;

```
id: String, // this is timestamp
userId: String,
point: String,
type: String
```

and i need an database query with all these arguments. but with a difference. It has to be at a certain time interval. so, tried this;

```
user.find({
    $and: [{ id: { $gte: start_date } }, { id: { $lte: end_date } }]
}).exec()
```

but how can add other arguments (`userId`, `type` and if have a `point`) in this query? I searched all day but I could not find it.

Comment: you can add those arguments inside one more `$and` if you want all conditions to be satisfied otherwise you can add them into one `$or`.

Comment: I didn't know how many argument we can put in same `$and` or `$or`. Thanks for this reply. I'm glad for your help. @Yogesh.Kathayat

Comment: No problem. :-)